# How to solve ' StagingBucket already exists' when I try to Bootstrap?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy my python aws cdk stack.

Reminder, the steps are:

```bash
cdk init app --language python
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
cdk synthesize
cdk bootstrap
cdk deploy
```

When I reach the `cdk bootstrap` I get the following error:

```
CDKToolkit: creating CloudFormation changeset...
12:17:23 PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::Bucket       | StagingBucket
cdk-hnb659fds-assets-#########-us-east-1 already exists
```

There actually is a bucket with that name, but it's not mine (it belongs to my co-worker) and it contains files (I can't delete it)

How can I solve this?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Why did your coworker create this bucket? Are you sure this bucket isn't part of a bootstrap stack?

Comment: Its the template in the cdk.out dir. when done SYNTHing, the cdk.out folder gets added which contains the bucket name and the configurations etc..
And because me and my colleague use the same AWS account, the same template with the account name is added.
So I tried to change the configurations in the assets files, but didn't work.

Comment: You only have to bootstrap an environment once - if your colleague has done it already, you don't have to bootstrap again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the overlapping resources and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately I have S3 with 'region not found` error and unable neither view, modify , delete it (

Answer (score -1):

I tried using this flag and it seems about right.

(Override the bucket name)

`cdk bootstrap --bootstrap-bucket-name majdvpc-stg`

Comment: Don't do this - bootstrapping is for the environment, not the stack. Once an account has been bootstrapped, its good for ALL cdk interactions with that account, no matter from what user/identity. Doing this just duplicates resources that cost you money that you don't have to do.